# In Remix I use a javascript to test the contract but estimateGas call is timed out

Tags: remix, javascript

I use the following code and the call estimateGas is timed out (in the Remix environment):

```
const [acc0, acc1] = await ethers.getSigners();
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(web3Provider);
const signer = provider.getSigner()
let Token = new ethers.ContractFactory(metadata.abi, metadata.data.bytecode.object, signer);
let token = await Token.deploy();
await token.deployed()
let tx = await provider.estimateGas({
        from: acc0.address,
        to: token.address,
        value: 1000,
        gas: 2000000
});
```

what is the reason? The same call doesn't work for any from&to addresses (e.g. acc0 -> acc1). Actually I need to transfer some ETH from the acc0 to the contract address in the code. I do not want to use a custom payable method for this. The contract has the 'receive' method. But the trasfer transaction is timed out as well. That is why I tried a simplier call 'estimateGas'.
At the same time the call "await provider.getBalance(token.address)" works perfectly.
Any help please :)

BTW: same code works perfectly with Ganache provider from the remix.

Comment: In Remix, go to the settings and look for the "Timeout" section, then increase the "Execution timeout" value. Is Remix logging any errors?

Comment: I use the web version. May this be a reason for the problem? I couldn't find an 'Execution timeout' option there. The error in the in the console is the following: "Message: Timeout of 50000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.". I will try the desktop version.